# Calling vbscript function from html button

Tags: html, vbscript

Don't be surprised if what I'm doing is completely wrong or if the solution is obvious.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    Function AddPrinter()
        Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\a2031slhsfile1\2031CAT-T113-HP4014dn"
        objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\a2031slhsfile1\2031CAT-T113-HP4014dn"
        MsgBox "The printer was added and set as the default printer."
    End Function
</script>
```

I added the above vbscript to an HTML document in the head section and one of the buttons has the following property:

```
onclick="AddPrinter()"
```

I didn't find much about this when searching on Google for an hour. What I did find didn't work. How does it know whether you're calling the function from javascript or vbscript or whatever anyway?

I get this error:

```
SCRIPT429: ActiveX component can't create object: 'WScript.Network'
```

Comment: You can't do that from a webpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Internet Explorer security settings prevent the creation of the ActiveX control. You need to allow "initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting".

Comment: That's what I did to fix it but I forgot to come back to this question when I was done. Better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, `WScript.Network` works just fine in IE, at least up to version 8. 
As about `OnClick`, its default assignation (whether run `JavaScript` or `VBScript`) 
depend on script content in the page. If your page has scripts in both 
languages (`JavaScript` and `VBScript`), then `JavaScript` is default, i.e.:

```
onClick="MyFunc()" 'is equal to:
onClick="javascript:MyFunc()"
```

In seach case you'll need to use explicit language modifier to run your `VBScript`.

```
onClick="vbscript:MyFunc()"
```

But if your page contain only `VBScript` then that not necessary.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
      Sub Hello()
          Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
          If IsObject(objNetwork) Then
              MsgBox "Its working"
              MsgBox "Computer Name = " & objNetwork.ComputerName
          Else
              MsgBox "Not working"
          End If
      End Sub
      Sub btnTest2_OnClick()
          Hello()
      End Sub
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="Hello()">Test 1</button>
    <input type="button" value="Test 2" id="btnTest2">
    <input type="button" value="Test 3" onClick="Hello()">
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. And if you not change your IE security settings, as Ansgar Wiechers suggest then you'll need to confirm (on first click).

[image]

Comment: Works in IE9 as well. And depending on the security level and/or manual zone configuration there won't be a prompt.

Comment: I added the vbscript: before the function and added all of those tests but it's still getting the same error. It's definitely not getting past the CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Answer (score 2):

You may elect to bypass the security settings of the Internet Explorer completely by saving the file as an HTA rather than an HTML.
HTA's are hyper-text applications that are written as htmls and use the Internet Explorer as a GUI, but are not restricted by the same security concerns as an HTML. the only change you need to make is change the file extension from *.html to *.hta.