# What's wrong with this VBScript code? When I press on the button, the msgbox doesn't open

Tags: vbscript

What's wrong with this VBScript? When I press on the button, the msgbox doesn't open..

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="VBScript"> 

Sub showMsg 
    MsgBox "Hello";
End Sub

</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<button onclick="showMsg">Show Message</button> <p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling vbscript function from html button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741042/calling-vbscript-function-from-html-button)

Comment: You would probably be better of calling a Javascript function rather than a VBScript one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z7ye5ke(v=vs.84).aspx) .. Instead of calling the function from the button as you do in JS, its the name of the VB function's relation to the name of the button that matters.

perhaps:

```
Sub showMsg_OnClick
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

form:

```
<button name="showMsg">Show Message</button>
```

**BUT** also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11) VB Script is on its way out and may have limited functionality in current versions of IE and Win10's Edge.

If your environment is XP it might work, doesn't work for me but you are not looking at VB script unless to support legacy code.

**EDIT:**
You can get the VB script code to work in IE if you go into developer tools (F12) and set the IE version to 10 or older.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how am I able to run VBScript else than in the browser?

Comment: @rey VB script is a browser implementation of vb6 and/or vba.  In MS Word Alt+F11 will get you to an environment where you can run vb code.

Comment: Thanks Steve, helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually invoked the sub.  Try `<button onclick="showMsg()">`

Comment: So, I just ran a quick test, and I see the issue.  Steve hits on it in his answer regarding limited functionality in current versions of IE.  I ran the test in IE 11, and hit F12 to bring up the developer tools.  In Edge mode, clicking the button does nothing.  I changed the rendering mode to IE 7, and when clicking the button the messagebox appears as expected.

Comment: Oh, and the test behaves exactly the same way regardless of the use of parentheses or specifying VBScript. `<button onclick="showMsg">` `<button onclick="showMsg()">` `<button onclick="VBScript:showMsg">` and `<button onclick="VBScript:showMsg()">` all behave the same way.  Nothing in edge, proper messagebox in IE7 mode.

Comment: You are right. I degraded IE to version 7 and it worked!